# Coordinate transformations and interpreting what the Jacobian determinant describes

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, coordinate-systems

Apologies for a perhaps rather trivial question, but I really want to get the concept cleared up in my head.

I understand that when one changes from one coordinate system there is an appropriate transformation between the coordinates of each system.

This coordinate transformation induces a transformation of the corresponding coordinate volume element of the form $$dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}=\lvert J\rvert dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$$ where $J=\left(\frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)$ ($\mu ,\nu =1,2,3$) is the Jacobian the the coordinate transformation. (also assuming that the set of coordinates $(y^{1},y^{2},y^{3})$ are Cartesian, hence having a coordinate volume element $dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}$).

Is it correct to say that $\lvert J\rvert$ describes the local dilation (stretching, compression,...) of the coordinate volume element $dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}$ relative to the the (new) coordinate system $(x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})$?

By this I mean that in general the transformation between the two sets of coordinates will be non-linear and so the coordinate lines defined by $(y^{1},y^{2},y^{3})$ will be mapped to curves in the new coordinate system and so relative to the new coordinate system $(x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})$ the coordinate volume element will be distorted from it's Cartesian form $dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}$. Instead, it will locally be given by the volume of the corresponding parallelepiped formed by vectors directed along the images of the coordinate lines, $y^{1}(x^{1},x^{2},x^{3}),\;\; y^{2}(x^{1},x^{2},x^{3}),\;\; y^{3}(x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})$.

Apologies if this is a little convoluted, but I really want to get an intuitive understanding of what the mathematical expression $dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}=\lvert J\rvert dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ is actually describing?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sense is correct.  $J$ gives a scale factor by which an infinitesimal volume $dV$ is transformed to another coordinate system.  Keep in mind that volume is a coordinate independent idea.  So if you are using two different coordinate systems to describe the same volume, $J$ kind of gives you the scaling between the two notions of volume in the two coordinate systems.  It really doesn't have anything to do with orthogonality (i.e. are the coordinate axes perpendicular to each other).  It more so has to do with the fact that some coordinate systems $dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ captures different amounts depending on the particular location of the coordinate system.  In the simplest case consider the polar coordinate system in the plane.  A unit of volume $drd\theta$ changes with the distance from the origin $r$ so we need the correction factor $J=r$ to account for this dependence so we get $dV = r\cdot drd\theta$.  If you examine the units you will see that this makes sense.

EDIT:

You can think about J as a *local* unit conversion.  Just like you convert between inches and centimeters.   Now imagine that the conversion factor between inches and centimeters was not constant, but depended on your position in space.  That is what the Jacobian is doing.  It is giving a local unit conversion at a point in space.  One unit just happens to be $dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ and another unit is $dy^{1}dy^{2}dy^{3}$.  The Jacobian gives us the conversion factor between them.  The Jacobian could be 1 (i.e. rotation and shear cases), it could be constant (i.e. stretching, contracting) and it could vary from point to point.  In some cases it could also be zero (i.e. Lat-Long coordinate system at North pole).

Comment: So is the reason why the coordinate volume element in Cartesian coordinates is simply $dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ simply because the volume measured by $dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ is independent of location within the coordinate system (is this not also to do with the fact that the basis is coordinate independent in such a coordinate system)?
It confuses me as in my rudimentary understanding I always thought that the reason why the coordinate volume element is $dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}$ in Cartesian coordinates is because ...

Comment: ... the coordinate lines form a rectilinear grid and so the coordinate volume element is simple a cube?!

Comment: "So is the reason why.. is independent of the location?" yes.

Comment: "coordinate lines form a rectilinear grid and so the coordinate volume element is simple a cube"  -- Yes, that too.  But keep in mind that the coordinate system could be stretched in one direction and still be rectangular.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info in your answer. Would it be correct to say that for a general (curvilinear) coordinate system, the Jacobian describes the local dilation (i.e. Stretching, compression, etc. at each point) of the coordinate volume element relative to a Cartesian coordinate system (if we consider the case $dxdydz =Jdudvdw$, where $(x,y,z)$ is Cartesian and $(u,v,w)$ is an arbitrary curvilinear coordinate system), although the geometric volume doesn't change, the way in which it is measured (i.e. how it is partitioned up) does depend on the coordinate system we choose?!

Comment: Yes, you could think about it that way.  Just keep in mind that the assumption that one of the coordinate systems in Cartesian is not necessary.  They could both be curvilinear coordinate systems.  Your last statement is correct

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, that's a good point. I tend to think of Cartesian to curvilinear (as opposed to curvilinear to curvilinear) as this makes more sense in my head when I try to visualise it, and also how I have seen the Jacobian informally derived. In general then, I guess it would be of the form $Jdx^{1}dx^{2}\cdots dx^{n}=\tilde{J}dy^{1}dy^{2}\cdots dy^{n}$?!

Comment: Yes or just $dx^{1}dx^{2}\cdots dx^{n}=Jdy^{1}dy^{2}\cdots dy^{n}$ because the Jacobian just relates volumes between one coordinate system and another.  The way that you wrote it, both would tie back to a third coordinate system (i.e. $Jdx^{1}dx^{2}\cdots dx^{n}=\tilde{J}dy^{1}dy^{2}\cdots dy^{n} = dz^{1}dz^{2}\cdots dz^{n}$).

Comment: What confuses me about that is that in all the examples I've seen they always consider a mapping between a Cartesian coordinate system and some other coordinate system $(x,y)$, most often the polar coordinate system $(r,\theta)$. Thus, in 2D (as in your example), the $(r,\theta)$ coordinate volume, relative to the coordinate system $(x,y)$ is given by $dxdy=rdrd\theta$....

Comment: ...I have never seen an example where one starts off in, for example, the polar coordinate system $(r,\theta)$ and then maps to another curvilinear coordinate system. Would one have something like $``drd\theta=Jdudv"$?